# When do you delete an Facebook app Request?

Tags: facebook

The documentation says that the app is responsible for deleting it's own requests. From a application design perspective, when is the best time to delete a request? Are there cases where the request should never be deleted?

btw, this is what I mean by deleting requests...

`$facebook->api("/$full_request_id",'DELETE');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#deleting) the most appropriate time to delete a request is immediately after the user is taken to your canvas application from clicking on a request. This removes the request from the various notification channels and updates the request counter. I would recommend a global hook that is configured to monitor the inbound Facebook request_ids GET parameter, look up the appropriate Facebook requests, optionally update your internal request/invite tracking, and delete the request once processed.

I don't believe there are any [official policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) regarding deleting your own application requests, and it would make sense to delete pending requests early, e.g. if the request is for a time-sensitive action that has past.

Comment: From the docs: "When a user is directed to your app by clicking accepting a Request you must delete the request after it has been accepted." 
You said: "the most appropriate time to delete a request is immediately after the user is taken to your canvas application from clicking on a request"
Are you sure that these two statements are equivalent?

Comment: I might've spoken too soon on that, it all depends on how you define the acceptance criteria for a request within your application, which is why Facebook does not automatically delete the request on click. Requests can be used for new users (invites) or existing users (notifications) of your application, so the criteria might be defined as simply getting users to install and visit your application. Once that's met, it makes sense to delete the request immediately upon an authenticated visit.